# Getting the index of the minimum value in each slice of `ndarray`

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to do something that should be straightforward and can be accomplished in a *for-loop* but I am trying to avoid that.

I would like to get the **index** of the minimum value in each slice along a certain axis of a `numpy.ndarray`, **a**. I am more interested in the index than the value itself. I use the index to get a value from another 2D array with shape equal to the first 2 dimensions of **a**.

Here is a naive implementation using a *for-loop*:

```py
a = np.random.randint(0, 10, 60).reshape(3, 4, 5)
print(a)
for i in range(a.shape[-1]):
    idx = a[..., i].argmin()
    print('Slice:', i, '| Index:', idx, '| min value:',
          a[..., i].flat[idx])
```

Out:

```py
[[[1 9 4 0 7]
  [6 3 1 6 8]
  [7 8 2 0 2]
  [8 6 1 6 5]]

 [[8 7 0 6 9]
  [7 2 6 4 5]
  [3 4 9 2 9]
  [1 4 8 0 7]]

 [[1 4 6 6 2]
  [9 9 5 6 7]
  [6 2 8 9 9]
  [3 9 8 5 4]]]
Slice: 0 | Index: 0 | min value: 1
Slice: 1 | Index: 5 | min value: 2
Slice: 2 | Index: 4 | min value: 0
Slice: 3 | Index: 0 | min value: 0
Slice: 4 | Index: 2 | min value: 2
```

I realise I can pass an `axis` keyword argument to `argmin` but that does not produce the result I am looking for.

Comment: So what is the result you are looking for?

Comment: @Jondiedoop a vector with `a.shape[-1]` elements that contain the indices of the minimum value. In this case `[0, 5, 4, 0, 2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the specific case given in your question, you can reshape your array, then use `argmin`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[[1, 9, 4, 0, 7],
...   [6, 3, 1, 6, 8],
...   [7, 8, 2, 0, 2],
...   [8, 6, 1, 6, 5]],
...
...  [[8, 7, 0, 6, 9],
...   [7, 2, 6, 4, 5],
...   [3, 4, 9, 2, 9],
...   [1, 4, 8, 0, 7]],
...
...  [[1, 4, 6, 6, 2],
...   [9, 9, 5, 6, 7],
...   [6, 2, 8, 9, 9],
...   [3, 9, 8, 5, 4]]])
>>> a.reshape(-1, a.shape[2]).min(axis=0)
array([1, 2, 0, 0, 2])
>>> a.reshape(-1, a.shape[2]).argmin(axis=0)
array([0, 5, 4, 0, 2])
>>>
```

The `shape[2]` comes from the fact that this is the dimension (in this case, the inner dimension, or rows), where you *don't* want to calculate the minimum across: you're calculating the minimum across the first two dimensions.

You also need the slice number: basically just the second index of your elements. That is easy, since that one is sequential, and is just:

```
slices = np.arange(a.shape[2])
```

Comment: Agree, reshape is the way to go there.

Comment: Nice. That works. I am embarrassed for not thinking of this myself. BTW, @9769953 why do you say *For the specific case*? I think this would always work as expected. No?

Comment: @9769953 I don't really need the slice because the other array, from which I get the value is a 2D array with shape equal to the first 2 dimensions of **a**.

Comment: @Shahar Specific case refers to the dimensions of the array, and across which of those dimensions you calculate the minimum.